# AngularJS $http.get request not displaying data in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-http

I am new to AngularJS, and after using the commands as shown in several youtube tutorials and reading the documentation, I cannot seem to get the data displayed on an API, using $http.get() request.

JavaScript and html code:

```js
var exampleApp= angular.module('app', ['ionic']);

exampleApp.controller('exampleController', function($scope, $http){
  
  $scope.getData=function(){
      $http.get("https://p3ddibjuc6.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries")
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.Date= data.Date;
      $scope.message= data.message;
    })
    .error(function(data){
      alert("error");
    })
  };
} );
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="exampleController">
        <button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="getData()">click</button>
        <br>
        MESSAGE: {{message}}
        <br>
        Date: {{Date}}
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: I cannot get the data from the API to be displayed on the html screen

Comment: the response of the api. (data) have the attribute Date?

Comment: @JesusCarrasco  the API (https://p3ddibjuc6.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries) stores the data regarding "Date" and "message" which I am trying to display.

Comment: uh, no it doesn't. Look at what it returns. message is a property of one of the objects in the Items property, not of the top level json object.

Comment: @KeshavSharma could you post the answer of the api, i have issuse with my proxy.

Comment: @Jesus {"Items":[{"Date":1499896074486,"message":"yo"},{"Date":1499977824999},{"Date":1499976641492},{"Date":1499976928878,"message":"July 13th"},{"Date":1499896774918},{"Date":1499883376762,"message":"yo"},{"Date":1500311063237,"message":"17th July"}],"Count":7,"ScannedCount":7}

Comment: as a test, try $scope.message= data.Items[0].message;

Comment: @GarrGodfrey that works!!! however, how would I display all the elements in Items, without mentioning the index positions? Right now, I can only see the 1st message and 1st date, but I would like to see the entire list

Comment: @GarrGodfrey thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var exampleApp= angular.module('app', ['ionic']);

exampleApp.controller('exampleController', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.getData=function(){
      $http.get("https://p3ddibjuc6.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries")
    .then(function(response){
      var data = response.data;
      $scope.Date= data.items[0].Date;
      $scope.message= data.items[0].message;

//for iterate do somethin lik this
      $scope.info = data.items;
    })
    .catch(function(response){
      alert("error");
    })
  };
});
```

that if you want the first Date and Message i you want all.
yo need to use ng-repeat in you html to iterate the data from api.

in the html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in info"> 
Date: {{item.Date}}
message: {{item.message}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad . to help !!

Comment: if the answer help please check the answer like correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ng-repeat directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to show a list of data:

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in Items"> 
      Date: {{item.Date | date}}
    <br>
      MESSAGE: {{item.message}}
  </div>
```

The `̶.̶s̶u̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶` and `̶.̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶` methods are deprecated. Instead use `.then` and `.catch`:

```
  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(response){
      var data = response.data;
      $scope.Items = data.Items;
  })
    .catch(function(response){
      console.log("error: ",response.status);
  })
```

## The DEMO

```js
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])

.controller('exampleController', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.getData=function(){
    var url = "https://p3ddibjuc6.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries"
    $http.get(url)
    .then(function(response){
      var data = response.data;
      $scope.Items = data.Items;
    })
    .catch(function(response){
      console.log("error");
    })
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="//unpkg.com/ionic-sdk/release/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//unpkg.com/ionic-sdk/release/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="exampleController">
        <button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="getData()">click</button>
        <br>
        <div ng-repeat="item in Items"> 
          Date: {{item.Date | date}}
        <br>
          MESSAGE: {{item.message}}
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```